# jquery(elem).parents('form') returns unexpected nodes IE 6 & 8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom, parent

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<form><input type="submit"/></form>
<form><input type="submit"/></form>
<form><input type="submit"/></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parents('form').length);return false;
    });
</script>
```

The 2nd & 3rd button will alert "2" when clicked.

The 1st `<form>` will always be contained in the `parents()` returned value, WHY?

It doesn't appear in Chrome & Firefox, is it a bug of IE or jQuery, or my code?

Comment: I was about to write about using `console.log()`, then I realised IE6 wouldn't have a JavaScript console. Ouch. :P

Comment: And this bug doesn't appear when you replaced the form tag into others such as table & div.

Comment: non-repro on W7 IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/gLx7V/show/

Comment: My IE8 returns 1 for all buttons.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/gLx7V/show is right, thanks, I still could not understand it, but I find that the key point is that there is no body tag in my files.

Comment: Instead of using HTML to format your code, select the code and click the **{}** symbol in the toolbar to create a code block. Then you won't have to type &lt; and &gt; over and over -- text inside a code block is rendered as typed. On the other hand, outside the code block, in your description, you *do* need to type "&lt;" to make the < symbol appear (that's why your "<form>" was invisible. You don't need &gt; for >, though.

Comment: @Adi Or you can just put it in `code` - if you're writing HTML code in your post, e.g. `<form>`, I'd definitely wrap it in code. Otherwise I'd just say _form_ or **form** if I'm just discussing it by name.